# Is it possible to send email using the box-api v2?

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to send email messages to collaborators using the box v2 api? I usually do this through the web interface, but it would be nice to do it from the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to send email messages to collaborators via the API.The closest you would be able to do this is by adding a comment to a file. An '@' comment, which is possible to do via the API, would ensure that an email notification is generated by Box to inform them of the comment.

Rory

Comment: Is there a formal feature request place? This seems like a simple addition that would improve symmetry between the api and the web-based box.

Comment: I can put in a request on your behalf.